# Is this flight GPS data intentionally manipulated?

Tags: airspeed, groundspeed

Some flat Earth guy is trying to convince me that flight data is manipulated with and that planes travel faster in the Southern Hemisphere.
Now this is obviously not true, in the video speeds of over 800mph are recorded in some shady screenshots, most jet streams can't get you that fast, much less many flights doing this at the same time.

It's either the screenshots are faked, or that there is some explanation as to the discrepancy between the two numbers.

If anyone can clarify this for me I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: I think you're just wasting your time: you want to convince someone who thinks that "*data is manipulated*", using... data!

Comment: Arguing with an idiot is like wrestling with a pig: You both end up in the mud, but the pig enjoys it.

Comment: @ROIMaison  Can I borrow this?

Comment: You're probably right, I just wanted to know how I can show that it is manipulated or seriously misunderstood. But just making sure, the data in the video is NOT real?

Comment: @sophit of course! [just like I borrowed it ;) ]

Comment: A flat-earther faking screenshots?  Who would have thought it?

Comment: Have been bored about 2 minutes in, but he clearly states at the beginning that whatever he is showing you is a simulation. And that… it’s a globe. You can actually see the curvature on his simulation (!), he seems to believe in GPS (!!!), he doesn’t understand why we don’t receive ADS-B data over oceans… Yawn.

Comment: "Southern hemisphere": read the last 5 characters. Also GPS requires a spherical Earth. You can see position of satellites and how to calculate your position: if would be very difficult to build an alternate view -- In any case, everything can be true, *Allegory of Plato's cave* tell us so, but you can decide: you can live in a library discussing philosophy *ad infinitum* (and no conclusion) or just get a life (you can still discuss philosophy, but ...)

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots are easily faked.

I would describe arguing with a flat-earther as wrestling with a rubber octopus. There's nothing you can grab onto, and unlike you the octopus always has an extra arm.

Airspeed numbers are only as accurate as the GPS readings they are based on and the data transmission quality, and glitched data will yield false numbers. Fact-deniers are expert at zeroing in on things like that and disabusing them of such cherry-picking is a fruitless enterprise.

Comment: Fair enough haha. I really shouldn't let them get to my head.

Comment: Even in statistical science, there's a reason why a p-value is used. If you take enough measurements, you'll eventually get false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Uh wow. I managed to muster the courage to watch (mostly try to listen) the whole <strike>drivel</strike> video.

What you have to remember is that flat earthers fall into two categories:

- Those who are just plain stoopid™
- Those who know perfectly well that the Earth is not flat but just continue with the charade. Don't know if they do that just to take advantage of the plain stoopid™ people, if it's just for fun (hey, it's cool to be part of a "Society") or whatever other reason.

I hope for them that the majority are in the second category, but hey, whatever. You can make all the rational arguments you want, the first ones will just ignore them because they beleeve™, the second ones will ignore them because it's no fun. The good thing is that at least it does not kill millions of people like some beliefs do, just [themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Hughes_(daredevil)) (striking example of a flat earther who was in both categories at the same time: he didn't believe it, pretended to in order to raise money from the plain stoopid™, but was himself stoopid™ enough to try to send himself up in the air in a homemade rocket...).

But let's get back to the claims in that video.

Apparently the whole story is that a french guy took 2 weeks worth of FlightRadar24 data he just doesn't understand and played with it and found all sorts of... Well, nothing.

- The first part of the video is some kind of simulator doing a replay of a bunch of flights (accelerated many times). The simulator actually shows a globe, with visible curvature. Not sure sure what the point is here.
- Then the second part of the video shows a few southern hemisphere flights, and alleges that the ground speed given by FR24 does not match his own calculation of what it should be (by about 300 km/h, plus in one direction, minus in the other). The examples are LAN800/801 (Sydney-Auckland-Santiago and back) and QF27/28 (Sydney-Santiago and back).

  For instance he says that QF27 (flying West-East) was at some point shown by FR24 as flying with a ground speed of 557 knots (1032 km/h) while his calculations tell him the GPS data shows that the actual speed was 1319 km/h. Another example is LAN801 (flying East-West) shown at 458 knots (848 km/h) where the GPS data supposedly yields 548 km/h. So obvioosly™ the GPS data must be wrong/faked.

  I took the JSON data for a flight from FR24 and did the computations myself. While there are differences between the ground speed reported by FR24 and what you get when you compute the speed from the last two positions:

  - A lot of it can be explained by the fact that the timestamp (in the JSON at least) has a granularity of a full second. When records can be spaced anywhere down to 3 seconds apart, that makes a huge difference: 581 meters in 2 seconds is 1047 km/h. The same distance over 3 seconds is only 616 km/h!
  - I'm not sure if the timestamp is when the data was received by FR24 or by whatever receiver got the ADS-B message first, or when the aircraft sent it. Given the combination of ground based and satellite-based data, this can explain a lot.
  - Some discrepancies may be due to the switch from one source to another
  - Using the per-record speed, you would see it do things like 374 - 262 - 540 - 268 - 473 km/h etc, spaced 2 to 4 seconds apart. Obviously the ground speed does not change that much in such short periods of time! It's just a result of the timestamp rounding.
  - The speed data reported by FR24 is probably just an sliding average over a slightly longer period to smooth things out
  - Most importantly: while there can be a few differences over 300 km/h on individual records (mostly when the interval is very short, around 2-4 seconds, or when the interval changes significantly, which is probably the sign of a switch from one data source to another), they cancel each other out, and in the end, the average difference is only 2.5 km/h on the flight I looked at.
  - So no, there's nothing suspicioos™ here.
- They exclaim at the fact that ooooh, over the ocean where it's more difficult to compare whatever FR24/GPS data and reality (you can't have a bunch of flat Earthers checking that the plane is or isn't where the "Globers" pretend it is), there is a lot of data missing. Duh. Maybe trying reading the [data sources page of FR24](https://www.flightradar24.com/how-it-works) and understand that there are lots of places which do not have coverage?
- They marvel at the fact that planes over the North Atlantic suspicioosly™ fly very neat routes, lots of straight segments, on a number of nicely equally spaced routes, and this is all way too clean to be true when compared to the mess over the US or Europe. Ooooooh they discovered the [North Atlantic Tracks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Atlantic_Tracks).
- Ensues an explanation for the fact that there is very little data over the North Pole, but it may just be because it's difficult to manipulate lat, long data near the poles (probably the case if you didn't listen in school), but it may also be because "they" want to hide something. Sure, sure. Or it could just be because of lack of coverage as above, combined with the fact that the current avoidance of the Russian airspace makes most polar routes unusable at the moment.
- Small diversion alleging that there are no pictures showing the North or South Poles, it's either always masked or CGI. Yeah yeah.
- Then some discussion about suspicioos™ curved routes (as visible on their very funny <strike>flat earth</strike> azimutal equidistant projection), which are probably the proof of the existence of GPS towers (!). More like great circle routes...
- Then they find it highly suspicious that there are very few flights inside the Southern Hemisphere (the video does not show the images they're looking at at that point, but I supposed they mean transatlantic and transpacific routes). Well, indeed, there are very few because the market for them is very limited. Not sure what is suspicious about that.

Comment: Why did you do this to yourself? :p

Comment: @Chris  Very good answer though 

Comment: Really late, but great answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. That flat earther has blocked me already but it's good to have this information in case anyone else brings it up. Thanks a ton, you can rest now 